# Why doesn't referencing another Google Sheets tab work in a Conditional Formatting formula?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to reference a cell in a different tab in a conditional formatting formula.

For context, this is a tee sheet for a golf tournament.  The Attendees tab lists the players, the TeeSheet tab is my tee sheet.  Each foursome has a group number. I want even and odd numbered foursomes formatted differently on the tee sheet.

What I want for my formula is this:

```
=isodd(Attendees!$j2)
```

If I pop that into a cell on the TeeSheet tab I get a proper boolean value, so I know the formula itself is valid.

But if I try that, I get an invalid formula error.

All I can do is put the group number on the Tee Sheet using a simple "=Attendees!$J2" reference, then reference that in my conditional formatting rule (which proves that the isodd() formula can be used here):

```
=isodd($a2)
```

I really would prefer to access the group number on the Attendees tab, rather than creating an intermediate reference on the TeeSheet where it doesn't belong.

Can anyone suggest why this is happening?

Comment: This seems to be working fine on my end. Can you provide a sample working sheet that shows the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

In conditional formatting you cannot reference other tabs directly.

But you can do so indirectly. like this:

```
=isodd(INDIRECT("Attendees!J2"))
```

Typically, the way that you make these work for larger ranges is with an offset function.  something like this:

```
=ISODD(OFFSET(INDIRECT("Attendees!J2"),ROW()-2,0))
```

If you applied that to a range in your tab, say A2:A, it would return TRUE for every row that had an odd value in column J on the tab called Attendees.